# Complex differentiability and higher derivatives of given function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I have a question that goes:
Is $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(z)=z^2+z|z|^2$ differentiable at $z=0$? If yes, find $f'(0).$ Also, does $f^{(n)}(0)$ exist for $n \geq 2?$

So what I did was try to express $f(z)= u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and then try the Cauchy-Reimann conditions and check whether the partial derivates $u_x, v_x, u_y, v_y$ are continuous or not, and if $u_x=v_y$ as well as $u_y=-v_x$. What I found was $$f(z)=x^2-y^2+x^3+xy^2+i(2xy+x^2y+y^3)$$

For this, I found that the partials are continuous at $z=0$ and the C-R equations are also satisfied. I then found $$f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=2x+3x^2+y^2+i(2y+2xy)$$

I then tried to take to repeat the above method for $f'(z)$ to see if $f''(z)$ exists or not, and found that the C-R conditions are satisfied at $z=0$. But then I found $f''(z)$ and apply the same condition to check if the third order derivative exists or not and found that the C-R conditions are indeed not satisfied. So is the process for this part and my conclusion correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You left out the part where you verified the C-R equations. There's an error hidden there - in fact the equations are _not_ satisfied except at the origin. (can't say what the error was since you don't show us the calculation). Since $f'(z)$ does not exist for $z\ne0$, $f'$ cannot be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Since I'm talking about differentiability and not analyticity, isnt it only required to verify it at the point? If we're talking about analyticity, I need to check it in the neighbourhood. But differentiability needs to only be satisfied at the point which I'm looking for, which is the origin ($z=0$)

Comment: You **cannot** verify the C-R equations for $f'$ at the origin, because $f'$ simply does not exist near the origin. To use C-R you start with $f'=U+iV$. But there's no such thing as $U_x(0,0)$, because there's no such thing as $U(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\ne0$.

Comment: (If your equation for $f'$ were correct then yes, you'd only need to verify C-R at a point. But that equation $f'=2x+\dots$ is simply wrong (except at one point).

Comment: Ah I get it. Yes. So $f(z)$ satisfies CR equations at origin so $f'$ exists at $z=0$ only but not at other points, so the general derivative $f'$ is not valid at other points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This has been covered in comments, but the question should have an Answer...)

There's an error fairly early, in the parts you didn't show us: In fact $f$ verifies the C-R equations *at the origin*, but not at any other point.

Since $f'(z)$ does not exist for $z\ne0$ it's clear that $f''(0)$ cannot exist, since $$f''(0)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f'(z)-f'(0)}z.$$

That's so clear that bringing in the C-R equations for $f'$ seems silly. But just to clarify: since $u$ and $v$ are already taken, let's say $f'=U+iV$. Now $U$ and $V$ are undefined except at the origin, so there's no such thing as $U_x(0)$, as above. (Yes, if the C-R equations hold at one point then the function is differentiable at one point. BUt if the function  is defined at only one point the C-R equations cannot hold, becausethe real and imaginary parts cannot have partial derivatives...)